# View SPO Modern list in SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I'd like to ask if its possible to achieve something like this -> https://collab365.community/create-manage-sharepoint-list-teams-tab/?fbclid=IwAR0FhFIvH9S51ZNvJbcR_dtFzl0Xe2zljyNP-XJBBZZRLcZJF3FVtXIE4Gw in SPFX.

What i want:

- I want to create a SPFX webpart that will hold my New form, Edit form & View (item view). Those will be created in custom code using React on top of SPFX.
- I'd like to make use of the default sharepoint list (custom list) so i don't waste time developing a custom solution. Developing a custom solution wouldnt really help since Office Fabric UI does not have a quick edit list. There's no way to use Export to excel & have refreshable data and implementing the list with all the current features would take a lot of time.

So TLDR what i need is a way to use React in a list for New form, edit form & view. I'm looking for a way to embed the sharepoint list in my webpart like on the teams tab, but with my custom forms.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out reusable [PnP React Controls](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-property-controls)

- For example, there is `ListView control` [component](https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/ListView/)
- For New/Edit/View forms it's a bit more complicated. I have seen several different people write their own reusable React components/services that allow you to do CRUD operations in React against SharePoint. [For example](https://github.com/olegrumiancev/sp-listform-react)

Comment: The forms will be created with CRUD operations since i dont think theres any other way. I'm only looking for the list part. I'll take a look at the links you provided, thanks

Comment: I wasn't clear enough about components that allow you to do CRUD operations. What I meant is the wrappers that allow you to easily create forms. If you never created complex forms for SharePoint using react you will spend quite some time reinventing the wheel. For example, making people people work or Taxonomy picker, etc. etc. PnPJs Core helps with CRUD operations, but it does not have any connection to UI components whatsoever.

Comment: I took a look at the ListView control, but it doesnt seem to be the automated process that i am looking for. It just looks like Fabric UI Component migrated for SPFX (i dont see the point of that). I am already developing a custom list solution based on fabric UI (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/detailslist) and it looks exactly like the sharepoint one, but the problem is that i need to implement all of its features (and some i surely cant). Correct me if i'm wrong, but ListView seems to be just a Fabric UI Component for SPFX.

Comment: Yes, that's right. There is no reusable react component that behaves as the real modern list view. No one created it. So the only option is to use ListView. It's very limited, but that's the best thing there is.

Comment: Well thats a shame. Any idea if SPFX extensions could be used to overwrite the default behaviour of the New & Edit buttons on a list ? Instead of customizing with powerapps?